# Docker cloud service link for Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, httparty

I'm trying docker cloud (previously tutum) to deploy a rails app that uses httparty to get data from another REST API (also deployed in docker cloud). So, the code will be something like the following:

```
def get_service_response
  response = HTTParty.get("#{api_service_url}/foo/]"
end

def self.api_service_url
  ENV['SERVICE_URL']
end
```

We are running two HAProxies, one for the rails web and the other for the REST API. So, the Stackfile looks like below:

```
web:
 image: organization/web-image
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  tags:
    - deploy_tag
  links:
    - haproxy-service
  environment:
    SERVICE_URL: haproxy-service

service:
  image: organization/service-image
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  tags:
    - deploy_tag

haproxy-web:
  image: 'dockercloud/haproxy:latest'
  environment:
    - BACKEND_PORT=3000
    - BALANCE=roundrobin
  links:
    - web
  ports:
    - '80:80'
  tags:
    - deploy_tag

haproxy-service:
  image: 'dockercloud/haproxy:latest'
  environment:
    - BACKEND_PORT=8080
    - BALANCE=roundrobin
  links:
    - service
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  tags:
    - deploy_tag
```

However, my `get_service_response` method is failing with the following error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Failed to open TCP connection to :80 (Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 80)):
```

When I tried to curl from the terminal in the web container, I'm able to see a response from the service

```
echo $SERVICE_URL
# displays haproxy-service
curl $SERVICE_URL/foo
#I see the expected response
```

I'm wondering why the rails app isn't able to evaluate the service link from the httparty call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override the `base_uri` in `Httparty` (in our case it was `Nil`), we need to start the path to query as `http://` or `https://`. We fixed the above issue by setting our env variable as follows:

```
environment:
    SERVICE_URL: http://haproxy-service
```